# how to know if webview can scrolled? react-native

Tags: react-native, webview

I was finding out a way to know if `webview` can scroll or not, but I found nothing special. I am using `react-native-webview`. Is their any way to find out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-native-webview`
supports
`postMessage`
method, which lets you to send a message to your app from webview. If you want to track user scrolling, you can basically set up eventListener and inject that javascript inside your webview and then send scrollOffset with postMessage to your app (where you can handle that event). Or you can just pass postMessage wit payload `window.innerHeight` when the document in webview loads. In order to understand how postMessage callback works you can check my example app, which was actually created for another issue (see github description), but will suite this case as well.
https://github.com/GFean/webview-example-app